# Bash doesn't read .bashrc unless manually started

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bashrc

`bash` won't source `.bashrc` from an interactive terminal unless I manually run `bash` from a terminal:

```
$ bash
```

or manually source it:

```
$ source ./.bashrc
```

or running:

```
$ st -e bash
```

Here's some useful output I hope:

```
$ echo $TERM
st-256color

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

$ readlink /bin/sh
bash

$ shopt login_shell
login_shell     off
```

I'm on CRUX Linux 3.0 and I use `dwm` and `st`. I've tried using `.bash_profile` and `.profile` with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Why would it source it? Your default shell is not bash, but `sh`:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
```

In most modern systems, `sh` is a symlink to a basic shell. On my Debian for example:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug  1  2012 /bin/sh -> dash
```

In your case, `sh` is a link to `bash` but, as explained in `man bash`:

> If  bash  is  invoked  with  the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup
> behavior of historical versions of sh as  closely  as  possible,  while
> conforming  to the POSIX standard as well.  [...] When invoked as an
> interactive shell with the name sh, bash looks for the variable ENV,
> expands its value  if  it  is defined,  and uses the expanded value as
> the name of a file to read and execute.  Since **a shell invoked as sh
> does not attempt to read and execute  commands from any other startup
> files**, the --rcfile option has no effect.

and

> --norc
> Do  not  read  and  execute  the system wide initialization file
> /etc/bash.bashrc and the personal initialization file  ~/.bashrc
> if  the  shell  is interactive.  **This option is on by default if
> the shell is invoked as sh.**

So, since your default shell is `sh`, `.bashrc` is not read. Just set your default shell to bash using `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed it didn't matter since `/bin/sh` pointed to `/bin/bash`. I suppose this issue stemmed from not explicitly assigning the shell to `/bin/bash` when I originally created the user account.

Comment: Also, Debian/Ubuntu switched to `dash` for `/bin/sh` as part of the effort to reduce startup time.  This was hilarious when my users started asking why their shell acted differently.

Answer (score 51):

In .bash_profile make sure you have the following:

```
# .bash_profile

# If .bash_profile exists, bash doesn't read .profile
if [[ -f ~/.profile ]]; then
  . ~/.profile
fi

# If the shell is interactive and .bashrc exists, get the aliases and functions
if [[ $- == *i* && -f ~/.bashrc ]]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: @terdon Your answer is the correct one. My answer would only be valid if he was running `bash`. Nice catch, I missed that.

Comment: This might give you a few headaches if you run `bash` alongside another shell, such as `ksh93` which uses `.profile` by default.

Comment: If ~/.bash_profile doesn't exist, you can create it.

Comment: .bashrc in Debain-based OS, .bash_profile in CentOS/Fedora/Mac OS

Comment: @Mitoxys bashrc and bash_profile serve two different purposes irrespective of what distro/OS you are running bash in.